# Add or update attribute to an element and all sub-elements

Tags: r, shiny, htmltools

I'm working on a full page layout using `fillPage()`. For a box to be able to stretch vertically, all elements that define this box need to have a `style = "height: 100%"` attribute (or so I'm told). Is there a way to append/update the `style` attribute for an element and all sub-elements?

I have whipped up an implementation that appears to work for my case, but I'm probably missing some details.

```r
library(htmltools)

tagAppendAttributesAll <- function(x, ...) {
  if (!is.list(x)) return(x)
  if (inherits(x, "shiny.tag.list")) {
    x[] <- purrr::map(x[], tagAppendAttributesAll, ...)
    x
  } else {
    x <- tagSetChildren(
      x,
      list = purrr::map(x$children[], tagAppendAttributesAll, ...)
    )
    tagAppendAttributes(x, ...)
  }
}

tagSetFullHeightAll <- function(x) {
  tagAppendAttributesAll(x, style = "height: 100%;")
}

print(tagSetFullHeightAll(
  div(
    div(
      div("test"),
      style = "height: 400px; "
    )
  )
))
#> <div style="height: 100%;">
#>   <div style="height: 400px;  height: 100%;">
#>     <div style="height: 100%;"></div>
#>   </div>
#> </div>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstand your problem. Have you tried using the unit 'vh'. In one of my shiny apps I'm using this line:

leafletOutput("rutMap", width = '100%', height = '75vh')

Comment: Unfortunately, `vh` seems to be imperfect -- AFAICT it uses the size of the display, and not the size of the window. Also, I'm composing a grid of fixed-size and variable-sized elements. I might extend the example to clarify.